# How many vrf does linux kernel support and what system resource limits the vrf numbers?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, routes

Linux kernel now support a brand new vrf (Virtual Routing and Forwarding) architecture, which is different from the old net namespace solution.

Questions:

1. How many vrf does linux kernel support?
2. What system resource limits the vrf capacity?

I am a newbie in kernel source code, and cannot find information about the upper two questions.

I wrote a script to add 4096 vrf and set vrf device up in a openswitch x86 docker container, everything works fine.

script:

```
def main():
    for i in range(0, 4096):
        cmd("ip link add vrf%d type vrf table %d"%(i,i))
        sleep(50)
        cmd("ip link set dev vrf%d up"%i)
        sleep(50)
main()
```

log:

```
root@switch:~# ip link add vrf0 type vrf table 0 
root@switch:~# ip link set dev vrf0 up 
...
root@switch:~# ip link add vrf4095 type vrf table 4095 
root@switch:~# ip link set dev vrf4095 up 
root@switch:~# ip -d link show type vrf vrf4095
4098: vrf4095: <NOARP,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:78:87:9d:ca:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 
    vrf table 4095 addrgenmode eui64 
root@switch:~# ip -d link show type vrf | grep "NOARP,MASTER" | wc
4097   61455  485311
root@switch:~# uname -a
Linux switch 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My reference:

1. [Documentation/networking/vrf.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/networking/vrf.txt)
2. [drivers/net/vrf.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/vrf.c)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no limit to the number of VRFs you can create, and the only limits are the memory size (as you allocate memory for each VRF netdev you create) and the ifindex type limit (it is int, which is usually 32 bits), which is very high.